# Can not print C++ String when use lldb in Xcode8

Tags: xcode, lldb

It says:

```
xcode lldb no location, value may have been optimized out
```

Try:

1. make sure is deubg in scheme
2. optimisation leve is set to None
3. "Enable Address Sanitizer" is off.
4. Other C Flags is empty

Not Work

Comment: Please paste code and relevant context

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your binary has been stripped.  Did you specify `Build Configuration = Release` **AND** untick the the Debug Executable?

My C app is stripped by xCode 8 when I use these settings:

[image]